# How to describe both non-verbal and non-gesture communication?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose we had a technology that reads a person's brain wave and interprets it. Then it sends the interpretated message to the screen in front of another person.

What is the word used to the communication done in this process describe this process?

Answer (score 3):

[From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface)

> A brain–computer interface (BCI), sometimes called a mind-machine interface (MMI), direct neural interface (DNI), synthetic telepathy interface (STI) or brain–machine interface (BMI), is a direct communication pathway between the brain and an external device. BCIs are often directed at assisting, augmenting, or repairing human cognitive or sensory-motor functions.